# What are some good JAIN SLEE related books?

Tags: java, java-ee

Could you recommend some good reading materials related to [JAIN SLEE](http://jainslee.org/slee/slee.html)? Or Java in Telecommunications in general.

Comment: Not sure this is the correct stackexchange site for this question.

Comment: JAIN SLEE.....?

Comment: I always get a fast response from stackexchange related forums. I guess the reason I didn't get response for this is JAIN SLEE is not popular yet. @Mudassir, JAIN SLEE is kind of new. Something like EJB. But for telecommunication based applications.

Comment: There is no good stackexchange site for this question anymore. Programmers is just SO2 now.

Comment: I don't have enough rep here to close to vote as off-topic

Answer (score 1):

There aren't that many books on the topic, honestly.

I'd rather recommend that you look for [good material](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=JAIN%20SLEE) [online](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%2bjain%20%2bslee%20%2bjava), but these 2 books are OK (fair warning: we had them lying around at my office a few years ago - I worked for a telco company for a short period of time, but I'm not expert in this field at all):

- [Java in Telco, Solutions for Next-Generation Networks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471498262) (Jepsen, Anjum, Bhat, Tait)
- [Programming Converged Networks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471268011) (Jain, Bakker, Anjum)

---

*I like how things in telco, healthcare or multimedia (and others) are always "next-gen"...*

Comment: @Shamal Karunarathme: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if you felt it was appropriate **after** reading them :)